# Disable keyboard on textField in Jetpack Compose Android?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm doing a calculator. So I made my Buttons with numbers and functions. The expression that has to be calculated is in a TextField because I want users can add numbers or functions also in the middle of the expression, so with the TextField, I have the cursor. But I want to disable the Keyboard when users click on the TextField.

In XML, the solution is:

```
public static void disableSoftInputFromAppearing(EditText editText) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
    } else {
        editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        editText.setFocusable(true);
    }
}
```

#### My question: How can I do this in compose textField?

##In Compose, the solution is:

```
CompositionLocalProvider(
    LocalTextInputService provides null
) {
    TextField(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = { value = it },
        label = { Text("The Label") }
    )
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am also facing same issue

Answer (score 2):

```
CompositionLocalProvider(
    LocalTextInputService provides null
) {
    TextField(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = { value = it },
        label = { Text("The Label") }
    )
}
```